# Find SQL Server Instance on other computer on LAN

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have the following function to find a SQL Server instance. It works fine on local computer. Would you please tell me how to use this function to check an instance on other computer on a Local Area Network? I am using VS 2008 (.NET Framework 3.5) and SQL Server Express 2005.

```
Private Function MyInstanceFound(ByVal MyInstanceName As String) As Boolean
    Dim InstanceFound As Boolean = False
    Dim MC As ManagedComputer = New ManagedComputer()
    For Each SI As ServerInstance In MC.ServerInstances
        If SI.Name.ToString = MyInstanceName Then
            InstanceFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return InstanceFound
End Function
```

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
SKPaul

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can get the list of Sql Server instance(or SqlExpress) that are installed and exist in local network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297021/how-can-get-the-list-of-sql-server-instanceor-sqlexpress-that-are-installed-and)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another ManagedComputer constructor, like this one:

```
public ManagedComputer (
    string machineName
)
```

[ManagedComputer Constructor (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms194537%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Function GetServerList(ByVal cmbServers As ComboBox)
    Dim Server As String = String.Empty
    Dim instance As Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator = Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance
    Dim table As System.Data.DataTable = instance.GetDataSources()
    For Each row As System.Data.DataRow In table.Rows
        Server = String.Empty
        Server = row("ServerName")
        If row("InstanceName").ToString.Length > 0 Then
            Server = Server & "\" & row("InstanceName")
        End If
        cmbServers.Items.Add(Server)
    Next
    cmbServers.SelectedIndex = cmbServers.FindStringExact(Environment.MachineName)

End Function
```

Add combobox name txtservidores in form. Call function
GetServerList(txtServidores)